# Extract location of fires from MODIS sensor readings

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, hdf5, gdal, data-collection

I am a newbie in the field of data collection from satellite images. I need help parsing useful information from HDF5 datasets.The sensor reading im working with right now is `MOD14A2`(`Thermal anomalies`),from the MODIS satellite.It gives information of fires occurring around the world.The data we get is in the HDF5 format.I need  help in parsing this data(any python libraries).I tried using `gdal` but due to some format error its not getting converted.

Comment: The 2 most common Python packages to work with HDF5 data are `h5py` and PyTables (aka `tables`). I am familiar with both, and like each for different reasons. `h5py` maps datasets to NumPy arrays, so is easier if you are familiar with NumPy. PyTables has some nice tools to recursively "walk" the data. The HDF5 schema is "self-describing". That means you have to interrogate the file to get the schema. So you need to understand HDF5 groups and datasets before you start writing code.

Comment: `gdalwarp` command does work with MODIS HDF files. You may need to make sure you have sufficiently recent gdal, i.e. version 3. Installing `gdal` into a python conda environment may help with this. You will only be able to convert one band at a time.